# React prevent re-fetch when url params are unchanged

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an `ExperienceList` component that fetches all items on `mount`. The functionality I am trying to achieve will occur when the user clicks into one particular experience, then navigates back to the `ExperienceList`. Currently, a `fetch` is made each time.

I want to do a simple check to see if the `cityname` from `url params` matches the `cityname` found in `redux store`. If it's the same, bypass the fetch. If not, do it. 
Here are 2 approaches that I have tried, without luck:

**First Approach**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.match.params.cityname !== list[0].city) {
      readList(apiRequestParams)
    }
  }, [])
```

With the above approach, I get the console error :

> Cannot read property 'city' of undefined.

I am not 100% sure on why list is unavailable, since I am able to log it to the console. 
Here is the **Second approach**:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      readList(apiRequestParams)
  }, [props.match.params.cityname])
```

This approach does not work either, but I am more baffled as to why this is. As is my understanding, the variables appearing in the `dependencies array` of `useEffect` will cause the `function` to execute if and only if they are different between `function` calls. In this case, I can guarantee that `props.match.params.cityname` is the same between 2 different renders, yet a fetch is made each time.

Any insight on how I can optimize this process?

Comment: How is your component structure? are you sure that you can access the `props.match.params.cityname` from the `useEffect`? have you tried to save this prop into the state and check it that way?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I am able to console.log out its value, so I assume that means yes. as far as saving the prop into state, I was under the impression that this was an anti-pattern. Are you able to confirm this?

Comment: if `props.match.params.cityname` does not change but `useEffect` is still re-run each time it means component is actually re-created rather updated. Reasons for that are somewhere in parent tree. Either due to parent is re-created as well or because of `key` is different or because component's constructor function is declared inline so is referentially different on each re-render. just add `useEffect(() => {debugger;}, [])` to check this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The function readlist is actually the dep of useEffect, you have to tell the useEffect. or you can change it to the cityname param.

```
const [cityName, setcityName] = useState('cityname');

useEffect(() => {
  function getFetchUrl() {
    return 'https://...' + cityName;
  }

  async function fetchData() {
    const result = await readList(getFetchUrl());
    setData(result.data);
  }

  fetchData();
}, [cityName]);
```

or

```
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
  readList("https://" + cityName);
}, [cityName]); 

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
},[fetchData])
```

Comment: you can also pass url as props here if you want to, as long as it can trigger a rerender.

Comment: This answer unfortuntately doesn't work with the way my code is structured. apiRequestParams is an object containing all attributes of the body. It doesn't work by simply making a request to https://....../:cityname. The concern I have is: if props.match.params.cityname doesn't change, why is useEffect called?

Comment: I'm not sure how you direct from routes. If the link is directing to the same route with just a different param, it's not remounting, but instead receiving new props. I find another question here having same problem using the new router hook useParams() as dep that it will always trigger the useEffect So i guess it should be the problem of it. the best way to manage the dep is to useRef. Can you try to give it a ref of the cityName and use the ref as Dep?

Comment: BTW. I think you are calling readList(apiRequestParams) in useEffect which means useprops.match.params.cityname should not be the dep in this useEffect but the readList function should be. We should not tell the wrong dep to useEffect.

Comment: I have another assumption that because match isn't available until AFTER render() in stateful component, So I guess the useEffect will also have an undefined value first and then get the value after which cause the reRender.